# Uninstalled RAM and reinstalled it but now monitor won't display anything

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, ramdisk

**Background**: I'm planning to upgrade my RAM but I'm new to upgrading RAM on my own, so before purchasing and installing a new one, I went to find out how the motherboard looks and uninstalled one of the RAM and re-installed it, I just want to have some idea on how to install and re-install them but now my monitor won't display anything.

**Problem**: When I pressed the start button, the LED on the DRAM and the VGA lights up for a couple seconds but then they went off. My monitor won't display anything and when I tried to attach my keyboard to the back USB port, the keyboard light won't turn on, so there must be some problem in that too.

To be more specific, the DRAM led first lights up for a couple seconds, then it turns off, then the VGA lights up for a couple seconds, then turns off, then the DRAM lights again, then it turns off, then the VGA went on again and turns off, then the boot LED lights up very fast until it turns off and all of them turned off for a while, while the fan continues to work properly and the motherboard light is on.

Note that the only thing I did was uninstall one of the RAM modules and re-install it again., that is all. Everything was properly working before.

When I re-installing the RAM, I have heard the 'click' sound and they seem to have seated properly like it was before. I am not sure what the problem is and don't know what to do now.

**Specification**:

- **Motherboard**: MSI H310M PRO-VH PLUS
- **RAM**: DDR4 Silicon Power 2x4GB

Comment: Did you try pulling them out and then pushing them in again. Sometimes RAM modules will “click” in place, but are actually not inserted all the way.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yeah i have tried to push them as hard as i can, after the click i have tried pushing it to the maximum, i didn't do anything else nor try switching the ram because everything was working fine before, the only thing i did was detaching that one ram module. do u think maybe it catched dust or maybe i have unintendedly broke some part or something?

Comment: 1)Unplug the power cord, press the power button for 10sec, reconnect power cord & attempt to power-on. 2)did any cords possibly get unplugged even partially if you hand caught anything by mistake?

Comment: “…i have unintendedly broke some part or something?“ Maybe. Try booting it up without that RAM module installed. Your goal right now is to just get the system to boot; not max out the RAM. Also @gregg has good advice. Most of all — and I know this might be hard to do — but don’t panic! If nothing seems to work to get the system up and running again. Give yourself a break and do something else. Like take a nap or wait a day to revisit the issue.

Comment: @gregg I tried your advice, pressed the power button for 10 sec and reconnect the power cord while still pressing, again, same as before, processor fan and psu is working but monitor still won't turn on

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thank u for the advice :) I have tried to leave the issue but I can't rest well until the issue is resolved :( also I have tried ur advice, rebooting with only one slot and it still doesn't work, it stays the same, fan working, mobo light is on, but monitor is off.

Comment: If the motherboard detects an error, the corresponding debug LED will stay lit, which here isnt the case. Do you happen to have a discrete graphics card along with onboard graphics ? If so, try connecting to your onboard graphics.